# Ember 2 render parent page on zoom out in background

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, rendering, css-animations

i am new to ember, could you please give me a direction:

i am working on zoom out effect with css:
say,

- there are **foo** route and **foo.bar** route
- we are in the **foo.bar** route
- when navigating using breadcrumbs to **foo**:

  - **foo.bar** template zooms out to a position where square (see twiddle) with title "foo bar" on a **foo** template is
  - **foo** template is rendered behind **foo.bar** template before zoom out effect, so that while **foo.bar** is zooming out - **foo** template is already visible behind it

here is the code for zoom out and following transition to parent route: [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c9ea34b2fda66ec120d6d47b7f689b81?openFiles=foo.index.template.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.click-me.hbs&route=%2Ffoo%2Fbar)

so, main questions i have are:

- how to render a template to get the described effect in ember 2 with pod structure
- how to get coordinates of child square on parent template, so that it is known to where we should make translation

any advice is appreciated.

thank you!

Comment: Have you checked out [liquid-fire](http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/) yet?

Comment: Not yet, man, I have heard about it and I will look into that, thank you for the suggestion. I would like to understand how to achieve that without external libraries in ember, though. I reckon it should be fairly easy (?)